# Spectral Cloning Plug-In for Mac?

Tags: plug-in, spectral, mac

Does anyone know of a spectral cloning plug-in similar to Elevayta's Clone Boy that is available for Mac?  Trying to avoid using an AU wrap. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly a plug-in, but looks like Metasynth does this amongst other things and is available for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Paul Frindle's Dynamic Spectrum Mapper (DSM) can capture a spectral and compression map from one track and apply it against another. Available as an RTAS/AU/VST plug-in for Mac.

http://www.proaudiodsp.com/products/dsm/

Comment: Nice one, cheers AdaBoy